# Delete record from SQL Server by date and ignore time stamp

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Script to delete by date not working due to time stamp. If I have right time stamp as actual record from table then it does delete record but I need to ignore time

```
USE [abc]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[COURSE_INSTANCE_EK]
  WHERE [BAInstanceCacheDate] = '2016-12-20 00:00:00.00' 
GO
```

Comment: Did you try using `CAST` - like `CAST(BAInstanceCacheDate AS Date) = '2016-12-20'`

Comment: What is the datatype of `BAInstanceCacheDate`?

Comment: is dateTime....

Comment: Cast it to date then. The optimizer is smart enough to use any underlying index to find rows that have a matching date, no matter the timestamp

Comment: casting worked but it delete record which are not even 2016-12-20

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
Declare @tbl table (id int,dt datetime)

insert into @tbl values(1,'2016-12-20 15:21:23.120')
insert into @tbl values(2,'2016-12-18 15:21:23.120')
insert into @tbl values(3,'2016-12-07 15:21:23.120')
insert into @tbl values(4,'2016-12-11 15:21:23.120')
insert into @tbl values(5,'2016-12-11 15:21:23.120')

select * from @tbl
select * from @tbl where convert(date,dt,0) = '2016-12-11'
delete from @tbl where convert(date,dt,0) = '2016-12-11'
select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to convert your data to a `date` datatype, which will remove the time part:

```
USE [abc]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[COURSE_INSTANCE_EK]
  WHERE cast([BAInstanceCacheDate] as date) = '20161220' 
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
USE [abc]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[COURSE_INSTANCE_EK]
  WHERE CAST([BAInstanceCacheDate] AS DATE) = '2016-12-20'; 
GO
```